How to decrypt Antiforgery token using the decryption key
Is there a way to decrypt in asp.net core application an antiforgery token if I have the decryption key.
In my asp.net mvc I added manually then machine key section like this:
<machineKey
    validationKey="..."
    decryptionKey="..."
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
/>

What I am interested is that, is there a way and if does, how can i decrypt the token in my asp.net core web api in middleware.
thnx
